# Has Emilio Estevez ever made a cameo as Charlie Sheen's brother?

Tags: character, casting

So I know Martin Sheen has made several cameo appearances on shows that Charlie Sheen has been the star, *Spin City* and *Anger Management*, as Charlie's father.  My question has his real life brother Emilio Estevez ever done the same thing?

Comment: He played a former friend of Charlie in the Two and a Half Men episode [The Devils's Lube](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1256402/), does that count or does he have to play his brother?

Answer (score 3):

Question is slightly unclear as to what's being asked, but I've provided several answers below to cover all bases;

If your question is 'have they ever played brothers on film'; then yes.
[Rated X](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0201776/) is one example, wherein the two real life brothers play two porn baron brothers from the 1960s.

If the question is 'have they ever showed up in a cameo role in each others films'; again, yes, more so than the previous. It almost seemed like a game to show up in each others films in the 1980's; Young Guns, Loaded Weapon, Wisdom, Never on Tuesday, Men at Work... the list goes on.

If your question is 'has Emilio Estevez ever made a cameo **as** Emilio Estevez in a Charlie Sheen text where Charlie Sheen is **playing himself** (or version thereof) and they make reference to being brothers?
I can only say this with 99% certainty, but no. Looking at a list of both their work, there are no films/tv that are metatextual enough for this to plausibly occur.

Comment: Specifically looking for tv shows where Charlie Sheen's character states this is my brother insert character name, where that character was played by Emilio Estevez.

Comment: @chcuk That...might be a little too oddly specific, though.